# Reason for space debris clustering in LEO

Tags: low-earth-orbit, debris

A [paper](http://ssi.org/2010-conference-space-manufacturing-14/proceedings/) ([Active Debris Removal: EDDE](http://ssi.org/2010/SM14-proceedings/Active-Debris-Removal-EDDE-ElectroDynamic-Debris-Eliminator-Pearson-Carroll-%20Levin.pdf)) contained this diagram of orbital debris.  This is the angle seen by the spacecraft horizontally and altitude vertically.

[image: Space Debris]

What are the reasons for the lines and clusters of objects on this scale?

Looking at lines around 1000 km and 1500 km, I'm wondering if a part of it is arbitrary numerology.  That is, scientists picking 1000 km because it's a round number.

Comment: Also "in-plane angle" probably does not describe inclination, rather something like true anomaly.

Comment: First guess: that's where we put them! If you could cross-reference those debris with the mission they originated from, I think you'd find the missions themselves occurred at those altitudes. The debris that didn't experience orbital decay hung around in their orbits. Why at those orbits? Round numbers: 1000, 750, 1500. Mmmm nice round numbers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The two bands near ~750km and ~975km (the more pronounced one) correspond with two large debris events: the [Fengyun 1C](https://celestrak.org/events/asat.asp) ASAT test occurred near -- but not quite at, although it's hard to tell from this plot -- the higher altitude (Gabbard plot [here](https://celestrak.org/events/FY1C-Gabbard.pdf) (PDF warning)), and the [Iridium Cosmos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_satellite_collision) collision occured at 789 km.

As for the higher band, I'm not sure, but some quick Googling produces [this](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2005ESASP.587...79J) relatively recent paper (from 2005) describing unknown debris objects near 1400km.

I'll add that "round numbers are nice" is likely not a reason for this, as orbit design is a relatively complex process, and mission planners rarely (if ever) enjoy the flexibility to just choose a number they like for altitude.