# Orbital decay - does it apply to space debris?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, debris

*Question 1*  -  [orbital decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_decay) - does it apply to [space debris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_debris)? Why so many debris continue to circle earth while ISS needs to be boosted to stay flying?
Is it because most debris are higher where orbital decay does not apply?

If so, than *question 2* - at what height orbital decay stops being a factor?

Thanks!

Comment: This should all already have answers on our site, did you check other questions tagged as [tag:debris]?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Space debris half life](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/999/space-debris-half-life) (and/or [Why is space junk so persistent in LEO?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9519/why-is-space-junk-so-persistent-in-leo))